# Connecting Node.js Application with Frontend (index.html)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post

```
const express = require("express");
require("../db/mongoose");
const Task = require("../model/user");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/mytask", (req, res) => {
  Task.find({})
    .then(tasks => {
      res.send(tasks);
    })
    .catch(e => {});
});

app.post("/mytask", (req, res) => {
  const task = new Task(req.body);
  console.log(task);

  task
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.send(task);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server started correcly");
});
```

This is my Express App, which is connected to a database.

```
localhost:3000/mytask/

{
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "This is my todo"
}
```

This works fine and stores the data correctly in my Mongodb Database with a POST Request in Postman.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Node</h1>

    <form action="/mytask" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="task" />
      <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to connect it to my frontend. But how to I do this? This is my html file. But the index.html does not know about the node server. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest you to use `res.sendFile` hence it will only send static HTML. you will not be able to pass variable to client side. there is better solution called `res.render` but first you would need to configurate view engine. (here is ejs solution)

```
const ejs = require('ejs);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

and after:

```
app.get('/url', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('yourejsFile')
})
```

if you want to write files in `html` extension you can use

```
const ejs = require('ejs);
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Comment: just came across "handlebars" which seem to work the same way. Same you :)

Comment: yes handlebars works same way, there are plenty of template engines (mustache,ejs,handlebars,pug...)

Comment: difference is how you get rendered variable inside html

e.g: if i am not wrong you get variable (in handlebars) like : `{{}}` and in ejs: `<%= %>`

Answer (score 0):

you can sen the request from your front end to localhost:3000,
and if you want the index to open when you visit localhost:3000 use res.sendFile()

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
})
```

make sure to import path module

Comment: thank you, that allows me to render the html. But how does the POST request get to the database then?

Comment: what did you use to send request ajax axios ..?
if you render the html you should be able to use post on localhost:3000/mytask